# How can i use ' ++ i ' inside this situation?

Tags: c#, list, random, draw

I want to draw a random name for an event where users can win items specified by their ID (1,2,3 etc.). The random name part is ok by now but how can i display the result like:

```
The ID : 1 winner is:  'the random name'
The ID : 2 winner is:  'the random name'
etc...
till ID : 27
```

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Names = { "Erik", "Levente", "Noel", "Áron", "Krisztián", "Kristóf", "Bence", "Roland", "Máté", "László", "Bálint" ,
            "Regina", "Brigitta", "Gréta", "Hédi", "Hanna", "Boglárka", "Jázmin", "Réka", "Alexandra", "Rebeka", "Lili", "Luca", "Zsófi"};

            List<string> alreadyUsed = new List<string>();
            Random r = new Random();
            while (alreadyUsed.Count < Names.Length)
            {
                int index = r.Next(0, Names.Length);
                if (!alreadyUsed.Contains(Names[index]))
                {
                 alreadyUsed.Add(Names[index]);

                 Console.WriteLine("The ID : 1  winner is:  " + Names[index]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use `++i`?

Comment: You don't have a variable called `i`, What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sayse he's trying to count at `The ID : 1  winner is`

Comment: Worth mentioning you have only 24 names, but you want to go *till ID:27*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (alreadyUsed.Count < Names.Length)
{
    int index = r.Next(0, Names.Length);
    if (!alreadyUsed.Contains(Names[index]))
    {
        alreadyUsed.Add(Names[index]);

        Console.WriteLine("The ID : " + alreadyUsed.Count + " winner is:  " + Names[index]);
    }
}
```

You do not need `++i`, you already have the position contained in `alreadyUsed.Count` that will increment itself as you use `alreadyUsed.Add(...)`.

[Try it online](http://tpcg.io/zA3rgM)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a refactored appraoch without that bad performing `alreadyUsed`. First I randomize the array, second I iterate and display each item with a incrementing index / id.

```
string[] Names = { "Erik", "Levente", "Noel", "Áron", "Krisztián", "Kristóf", "Bence", "Roland", "Máté", "László", "Bálint" ,  "Regina", "Brigitta", "Gréta", "Hédi", "Hanna", "Boglárka", "Jázmin", "Réka", "Alexandra", "Rebeka", "Lili", "Luca", "Zsófi"};
Random r = new Random();
Names = Names.OrderBy(_ => r.Next()).ToArray();
for(int i=0;i< Names.Length;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The ID : " + (i+1) + " winner is:  " + Names[i]);
}
```

Comment: why 7, both LINQ and lambda functions are around since C# 3.0

Comment: @dlatikay my mistake, I confused it